# Laplace transform of : $t^{\gamma-1} F(\alpha,\beta,\delta,t)$, where $F$ is the Gauss' hypergeometric function

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, integration, integral-transforms

What is the Laplace transform of : $t^{\gamma-1} F(\alpha,\beta,\delta,t)$, where $\gamma >0 $ and $F$ is the Gauss' hypergeometric function.

Thanks!

Comment: My trivial guess that this laplace transform equals a special function. :-D

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Mathematica seems to be able to evaluate this Laplace transform

Comment: That's right, but I need the computation method ..

Comment: Have you tried the Euler integral representation of the hypergeometric function? This will assume $\delta-\beta-\gamma>0$.

Comment: I think I can use the Euler representation because in my case : $t<1$ and $\beta<\gamma$ $(\beta =\gamma-1)$. but what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an explicit formula in the book:
A.P. Prudnikov, Yu.A. Brychkov,  O.I. Marichev. INTEGRALS AND SERIES, Volume 4. 
Direct Laplace Transforms. GORDON AND BREACH, 1992.

It is on the page 533 and is in terms of $_{2}F_{2}$ hypergeometric function. For special values of parameters for sure it can be simplified using the same book volume 3.

Comment: I don't have this book and it seems impossible to find it for free on the internet. Could you please put a capture of  page 533.

Comment: OK. Connect me by mathsms@yandex.ru

Comment: Any Idea if I need to compute $\int_{d}^{\infty}e^{-st}t^{\gamma-1}F(\alpha,\beta,\delta,t)dt$  where $d>0$?